# How to reset opacity of Pane?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm a newbie in JavaFX. I made a fx application it has a home and another jfxml file.

This is HomeContoler.java file for open another jfxmlfile

```
@FXML
public void actionIngredencesReg(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        mainHome.setOpacity(0.2);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Ingrdences.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root1);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
       // mainHome.setOpacity(1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when I click on the menu items it will works likes

this the close code of Ingredients.fxml file

```
@FXML
Label close_label;
```

this is a label, here in action

```
 @Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    close_label.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
         //this is code for close only science
            Stage stage = (Stage) close_label.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();  
        });
}
```

but after close Ingredients.fxml file home.fxml file be like this
[this is not needed for me][4]

I want to convert home.fxml file like this
[as like this after closing the ingredient.fxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJIjR.png)

i want to setOpcaity of home.fxml file into 1 after close the ingredient.fxml file

anyone can help me to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just revert the opacity when the stage is hidden:

```
stage.setOnHidden(e -> mainHome.setOpacity(1));
```

Comment: what is stage of this above code, ingredient.fxml or Home.fxml.?

Comment: Thanks for help me.